# VS2015 How to reference a Class Library (Package) project from a normal Class Library project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

**What I have:**

- I have a Class Library project(ProjectCore).
- I have a reference to some nuget
  packages from nuget.org with copy local so after build the output
  folder contains my DLL with the DLLs from the referenced nuget
  packages.

**What I need:**

- I want to create a Class Library (Package) project(ProjectUtils) that
  will be referenced from the ProjectCore.
- After build the ProjectCore output folder should contain the
  ProjectUtils.dll.
- The project type of ProjectUtils should remain nuget package. I need to be able consume it in another projects like nuget package.

**The problem:**

- I've expected the Class Library (package) to be referenced as a normal nuget dependency but when I try to add the reference I get: **A reference to "ProjectUtils" could not be added.**

Any thoughts?

Comment: That project template has a very sucky name.  You are mixing up CLR targets, your regular class library targets the desktop version, the sucky project targets CoreCLR.  Mixing isn't possible.  It is not very clear why you think you need to do this, just add a regular class library project.

Comment: I want to create two PS modules(Core and Extensions). Both modules have separate solutions and are setup as a separate components in a build system. Core solution contains a PS module project(Class library) +Utils project. Extensions has only PS module project(Class library). I want to reference the Utils class library by Core and Extensions projects. I want the Extensions project to be a NuGet package to be able to handle build time dependencies in a more civilized way. I prefer to use project.json instead of packages.config.So when I saw this project type I decided to use it. It didn't work.